# How can I remove commas in tnoteref in elsarticle.cls?

Tags: elsarticle

[image]How do I remove commas between successive foot note symbols in this modified `elsarticle` class?

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
    %replace first instance (first tnote)
    \patchcmd{\tnotemark}{\ding{73}}{\dag}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to path \string\tnotemark\space for \string\ding{73}}}
    %replace second instance (second tnote)
    \patchcmd{\tnotemark}{\ding{73}\ding{73}}{\dag\dag}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to path \string\tnotemark\space for \string\ding{73}\string\ding{73}}}
    %replace first instance (first tnote)
    \patchcmd{\tnotetext}{\ding{73}}{\dag}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to path \string\tnotetext\space for \string\ding{73}}}
    %replace second instance (second tnote)
    \patchcmd{\tnotetext}{\ding{73}\ding{73}}{\dag\dag}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to path \string\tnotetext\space for \string\ding{73}\string\ding{73}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1}}
\author{M. Author\tnoteref{t2}}
\tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.}
\tnotetext[t2]{Another title note.}
\end{frontmatter}
\section{Paper Material}
Some Text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should have been clearer; I wanted to remove the commas as the foot note symbols are being used at different places in the document. When using the symbol, at the second instance, it comes appended with a comma.

Comment: Your code *doesn't* produce the result you're showing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do it. However, the comma is just before `\ding{73}\ding{73}` in `\tnotemark`, so replacing it with `\,` is easy.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%replace first instance (first tnote)
\patchcmd{\tnotemark}
  {\ding{73}}
  {\dag}
  {}{}
%replace second instance (second tnote)
\patchcmd{\tnotemark}
  {,\ding{73}\ding{73}}
  {\,\dag\dag}
  {}{}
%replace first instance (first tnote)
\patchcmd{\tnotetext}
  {\ding{73}}{\dag}
  {}{}
%replace second instance (second tnote)
\patchcmd{\tnotetext}
  {\ding{73}\ding{73}}
  {\dag\dag}
  {}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1}\tnoteref{t2}}
\author{M. Author}
\tnotetext[t1]{This document is a collaborative effort.}
\tnotetext[t2]{Another title note.}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Paper Material}
Some Text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

There's also some misunderstanding about the notes. In `elsarticle` one distinguishes between title notes and author notes. The former use `\tnoteref` and `\tnotetext`, the latter `\fnref` and `\fntext`. Title notes are marked with symbols, author notes with numbers. You can avoid commas and replace title note symbols with the patches you have.

You can abuse `\tnoteref` also for author notes, but it's wrong as you only get at most two of them. Just remove, in the patch above, `\,` if you want to do this.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%replace first instance (first tnote)
\patchcmd{\tnotemark}
  {\ding{73}}
  {\dag}
  {}{}
%replace second instance (second tnote)
\patchcmd{\tnotemark}
  {,\ding{73}\ding{73}}
  {\dag\dag}
  {}{}
%replace first instance (first tnote)
\patchcmd{\tnotetext}
  {\ding{73}}{\dag}
  {}{}
%replace second instance (second tnote)
\patchcmd{\tnotetext}
  {\ding{73}\ding{73}}
  {\dag\dag}
  {}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{This is a specimen title\tnoteref{t1}}
\author{M. Author\tnoteref{t2}}
\tnotetext[t1]{Title note.}
\tnotetext[t2]{Author note.}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Paper Material}
Some Text.

\end{document}
```

Don't blame me or this site if your submission is rejected for not complying with the standard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, removing the comma does not make sense, since this will result in a sequence of three identical symbols, which looks like a single reference to a footnote.

If you really want it, just replace the second patch command

```
%replace second instance (second tnote)
\patchcmd{\tnotemark}{\ding{73}\ding{73}}{\dag\dag}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to path \string\tnotemark\space for \string\ding{73}\string\ding{73}}}
```

by

```
%replace second instance (second tnote)
\patchcmd{\tnotemark}{,\ding{73}\ding{73}}{\dag\dag}{}{\@latex@error{Failed to path \string\tnotemark\space for \string\ding{73}\string\ding{73}}}
```